# Debug JavaScript with Visual Studio 2010 and Firefox

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, firefox, visual-studio-debugging

Is it possible to degug JavaScript code in Razor views using Visual Studio 2010 and Firefox?  If so, how can I do it?

Comment: All I've tried is putting a breakpoint at the point in the JavaScript code at which I want to stop and attaching the process to visual studio.  The session does not ever break at that point and the breakpoint icon has a white diamond shape in it.

Comment: It means your code has some syntax errors, first build the project. Then it will show the list of errors in your project may be in markup or code behind. First solve the errors, later try again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for debugging javascript in Fireforx use FireBug plugin. It's impossible to debug javascript code in VisualStudio directly when FF is a browser

Comment: I wonder why they have never come up with a plugin/add-on for Visual Studio to be able to debug javascript code running in FireFox directly in Visual Studio. Sure, FireBug is great, but sometimes it just doesn't want to debug javascript anymore (it says script elements miss a required attribute while they are clearly there and then I cannot debug in javascript).

Comment: Think because they want you using Internet Explorer. As far as I remember it's possible to debug js code in VS when you surfing site with IE.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can no, visual studio client side debugging seems to need IE.  However there is an excellent javascript debugger called [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) you can use for debugging JS in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug javascript in vs2010 like this

```
var a = 'test' 
debugger // you can write 'debugger' anywhere you want you want break
```

then press F5